# Angularjs how to get URL referrer?

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, I have a login controller that is redirected to by every single page in the app if the user arrives at the page and is not logged in. After the login sequence, I would like to redirect the user back to the page that they came from. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use history.back() to let the user navigate to the page he was previously. This works in every case, except when the user navigates directly to the login page :)

Another solution is to pass a search parameter to the login page when you navigate from another page. From the login page you can then choose to navigate to the page of the search parameter if its present, and otherwise navigate to the "home page".

Comment: Thank you for your reply! history.back () is not suitable for use on my project, my project is a multi-menu navigation, and each menu to open an iframe page, if the page were the other menu operation, history.back (path) returns not right .so I need to get  referer.In addition to the method of passing parameters, angularjs does not provide a method to get referer obtain it? I'm sorry! My English is not very fluent.

Comment: No you cannot get the previous page or referrer in AngularJS, only if you pass the referrer yourself with search parameters or save the previous page by any other method. You can for example subscribe to the $routeChangeSuccess event and save the previous page.

Comment: If an answer here is the right answer that you are going to use, please mark it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can catch the route change and when the target is your login page, it could save the old route. After the Login you can redirect to the old route

```
angular.module('appName')
  .run(['$rootScope','$location', '$routeParams', function($rootScope, $location, $routeParams) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(e, next, cur) {
       if (next.path() == 'your/login/path') {
          $rootScope.savedRoute = $location.path());
          $rootScope.savedParams = $routeParams;
       }
    }
  }]);
```

I'm not sure if path() is the correct function, but i think you can see what i mean