# How to get request header referer url in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

it's possible to get a API request header referrer URL? `document.referrer` it's not working for me.can anyone guides me, please.

Comment: What part of `window.document.referrer` isn't working? This has been asked numerous times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36933673/how-can-i-retrieve-the-previous-url-in-angularjs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186453/angularjs-how-to-get-url-referrer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38520055/how-to-get-url-referrer-in-angularjs

Comment: it returns the same above URL for my case.